# Undefined offset error

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an mutidimention array that i want torename it keys :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEST1
            [2] => TEST12
            [3] => TEST13
            [4] => TEST14
            [5] => TEST15
            [6] => TEST16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => TEST2
            [2] => TEST21
            [3] => TEST22
            [4] => TEST23
            [5] => TEST24
            [6] => TEST25
        )
    )
```

So I did this an it worked :

```
foreach ( $data_1 as $k=>$v )
        {
          $data_1[$k]['bla0'] = $data_1[$k][0];
            $data_1[$k]['bla1'] = $data_1[$k][1];
            $data_1[$k]['bla2'] = $data_1[$k][2];
            $data_1[$k]['bla3'] = $data_1[$k][3];
            $data_1[$k]['bla4'] = $data_1[$k][4];
            $data_1[$k]['bla5'] = $data_1[$k][5];
            $data_1[$k]['bla6'] = $data_1[$k][6];
          unset($data_1[$k][0],$data_1[$k][1],$data_1[$k][2],$data_1[$k][3],$data_1[$k][4],$data_1[$k][5],$data_1[$k][6]);  

        }
```

but it displays me  : 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in...
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in...
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in...
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in...
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in...
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in...
Any source of this error ? Much appreciated!

Comment: is this your full array ?

Comment: No the array is to big to copy here.

Comment: @user3350731 It looks like at least one "sub array" that you're not showing does not have indexes 1-6.

Comment: i think some sub arrays are not containing six elements. for those array you are getting those notices

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array = array(
                    1=>array(
                        1=>'a',
                        2=>'b'),

                    2=>array(
                        1=>'c',
                            2=>'d'
                        )
                    );
    foreach($array as $key=>&$val){
            for($i=1;$i<=count($val);$i++){
                $val['balh'.$i] = $val[$i];
                unset($val[$i]);
            }   
    }
    print_r($array);
?>
```

This way you are passing pointer.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [balh_1] => a
            [balh_2] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [balh_1] => c
            [balh_2] => d
        )

)
```

This will be the output

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data_1 = array(array(0, 'test', 'test1'), array(0, 'test', 'test1'));




foreach ( $data_1 as $k => $v ){

    $data_1[$k]['bla0'] = $data_1[$k][0];
    $data_1[$k]['bla1'] = $data_1[$k][1];
    $data_1[$k]['bla2'] = $data_1[$k][2];
    unset($data_1[$k][0]);  
    unset($data_1[$k][1]);  
    unset($data_1[$k][2]);  

}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($data_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the most likely explanation is that some of your sub arrays do not contain 6 elements.

If this is valid and intentional (you intend for some sub arrays to contain less than 6 elements), then it would perhaps be advisable to make your code handle a variable number of elements in each array.

Something like this may work for you;

```
foreach ($data_1 as &$subArray) {
    foreach (array_keys($subArray) as $k) {
        $subArray["bla$k"] = $subArray[$k];
        unset($subArray[$k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine as it is. the problem is you're not checking for the length of the sub-array or if the element exists before trying to process it.

it's better to automaticall loop through the subarray so you don't have to explicitly call non-existent indexes for shorter subarrays.

```
<?php
foreach ($data_1 as $key => $val) {
    foreach(array_keys($val) as $i) {
        $data_1[$key]["bla{$i}"] = $data_1[$key][$i];
        unset($data_1[$key][$i]);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem

```
<?php
$data_1 =  array(
        '1' =>  array(
            0 => '0',
            1 => 'TEST1',
            2 => 'TEST12',
            3 => 'TEST13'),
        '2' =>  array(
            0 => '0',
            1 => 'TEST2',
            2 => 'TEST22',
            3 => 'TEST23')
    );

foreach ( $data_1 as $k=>$v )
    {
      $data_1[$k]['bla0'] = $v[0];
        $data_1[$k]['bla1'] = $v[1];
        $data_1[$k]['bla2'] = $v[2];
        $data_1[$k]['bla3'] = $v[3];

      unset($data_1[$k][0],$data_1[$k][1],$data_1[$k][2],$data_1[$k][3]);  

    }

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($data_1); echo '</pre>';
?>
```